# Is there efficient way to retrieve and use test data in Selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium, collections, apache-poi

I'm automating search functionality and want to perform data driven test on it. I'm using an Excel sheet to store the test data and using Apache POI libraries to read the same. This is how testdata stored.

[image]

I've one common class in my Framework to read the data from excel file where i have to pass the sheet number while calling the method as mentioned below :

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllData(int sheetNumber)
{
        list=new ArrayList<String>();
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
        for(int i=1;i<=sheet.getLastRowNum();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<sheet.getRow(i).getLastCellNum();j++)
            {
                System.out.println(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
                list.add(sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I'm facing trouble in how I use this data in my calling function. Somehow I'm able to mange at my level like:

```
@Test
public void searchRcontacts() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{

    LoginAnalyser.checkLogin();
    if(!(driver.getCurrentUrl().equals(PropertyFileReader.getProperty("dashboardURL"))))
    {
        driver.get(PropertyFileReader.getProperty("dashboardURL"));
        CommonMethods.waitUntilLoaderGetInvisible(driver);
    }

    //Calling the method from ExcelReader class
    Iterator<String> itr=excel.getAllData(7).iterator();  

    while(itr.hasNext())
    {  
        contacts.enterSearchText(itr.next()); 
        TakeScreenshot.passedScreenShot("Search_");
        LogWriter.logger.info("Search Text enterd");    
        contacts.clickSearchButton();
        CommonMethods.waitUntilLoaderGetInvisible(driver);
        LogWriter.logger.info("Search button clicked"); 
        TakeScreenshot.passedScreenShot("Search_Result_For");   
        assertEquals(contacts.getSearchResult(),itr.next());
        LogWriter.logger.info("Result : "+contacts.getSearchResult());   
      }  
 }
```

But it doesn't seem like an efficient way. Can someone suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: You can consider using data provider option which gives like iteration and other options.

Comment: @Murthi, I gone through them by my problem is I have test method in one file and Excel reader code in one common file. So I m calling the required excel data reader method from a test method

Comment: there is a option like data provider class in testng. You can keep the test method and test data provider in different classes.  like @Test(dataProviderClass = TestNGDataProvider.class, dataProvider = "testMultipleInput")

Comment: @Murti, thanks . Will try and updated you soon

Answer (score 0):

Consider using BDD methodology such as Cucumber or JBehave.  In your example, a story could be created:

```
Scenario: Positive tests

Given I am on the search page
When I enter <testdata>
Then the record is found

Examples:
|testdata  |
|narrendra |
|9422320101|
|jec       |

Scenario: Negative tests

Given I am on the search page
When I enter <testdata>
Then the record is not found

Examples:
|testdata|
|Alex$   |
|Mac100  |
```

You could also, in the case of JBehave, place the example data in a separate file, and use:

```
Examples:
.\tables\storyPosTestData.txt
```